# Cannot store variable values at RobotFramework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

For example, we have:

```
Get ticket value
        Wait Until Element is Visible    ${ticketDescription}
        ${ticketDescValue}=    Execute Javascript    return window.document.querySelector('p[class*="ticket-description"]').innerHTML.toString()


Verify if ticket value matches
       Element Text Should Be    ${some_locator}    ${ticketDescValue}
```

where, ${ticketDescValue} would be an expected text

Test Cases example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Ticket value is correct
    [Documentation]    OK: test test test
    [Tags]    Add to basket
    Go to some URL
    Get ticket value
    Navigate to product details page
    Verify if ticket value matches
```

Is there some way to share variables between existing keywords?
In Java I can use getters and setters for this case.
Or send parameters to method, etc...

How to implement it using Robot Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either set the variable value as a Global or suite variable using something similar to the below after your assignment line:

```
 Set Suite Variable    ${ticketDescValue}
```

Alternatively, you could return the variable from the first keyword and pass it as an argument into the second keyword

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to modify your `Get ticket value` keyword to return a parameter, and your `Verify if ticket value matches` keyword to take the ticket value as an argument. That way you don't need to use global variables.

```
Get ticket value
    Wait Until Element is Visible    ${ticketDescription}
    ${ticketDescValue}=    Execute Javascript    return window.document.querySelector('p[class*="ticket-description"]').innerHTML.toString()
    [Return]    ${ticketDescValue}

Verify if ticket value matches
   [Arguments]    ${value}
   Element Text Should Be    ${some_locator}    ${value}
```

Then your test would look like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Ticket value is correct
    [Documentation]    OK: test test test
    [Tags]    Add to basket
    Go to some URL
    ${ticket value}=    Get ticket value
    Navigate to product details page
    Verify if ticket value matches    ${ticket value}
```

I made all the parameter names different to emphasize that they do not have to be all the same - but you can make them all the same if you want.